# jQuery stop animation on focus hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frontend

I'm working on a UI module: a search form that shows/hide depending if the user has hovered over a target area, or still has focus on the input text field. I just have another tweak to take care off...

I want to be able to cancel the animation (e.g. fadeout) if I happen to hover over the target area. At the moment, stop() doesn't seem to do the job.

Tips greatly appreciated. TIA

---

Here's the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/s2wEu/

The current script:

```
var topbar_search_hotspot =  $('form[role="search"]');
var topbar_search_hideshow = $('form[role="search"] .row');

function fadeOutSearch() {
    var element = $('#s');
    if (!element.hasClass("focus") && !element.hasClass("hover") && element.val() == "") {
        $('form[role="search"] .row:visible').fadeOut("slow");
    }
}

topbar_search_hotspot.blur(function() {
    topbar_search_hideshow.removeClass("focus");
    setTimeout(fadeOutSearch, 1000);
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus");
});

topbar_search_hideshow.hide();
topbar_search_hotspot.hover(function() {
    if (topbar_search_hideshow.is(':animated')) {
        topbar_search_hideshow.stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
    } else {
        topbar_search_hideshow.fadeIn("slow");
    }
}, function(e) {
    setTimeout(fadeOutSearch, 1000);
    topbar_search_hotspot.removeClass("hover");
});

topbar_search_hotspot.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('#s').focus();
}, function(){
    setTimeout(fadeOutSearch, 1000);
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing `topbar_search_hideshow.stop().animate({opacity:'100'});` with `topbar_search_hideshow.stop(false,true).hide().fadeIn();` fix it as demonstrated in the following fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/7BDCB/

Comment: It seems to still go through w/ the fadeout. You can replicate the behavior by just hovering in-and-out of the gray area.